# Multiple HTML files connected to one JS file?

Tags: javascript

So if I have multiple HTML files connected to one JS file, when I run a code that uses the document keyword, does the code know which document I'm referring to? For example, in one of the HTML files, I have a div with the id of main in the body tag and in the js file, I created a new div to append to that specific html file. The code in the js file is basically var div = document.createElement("div") followed by document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div). My question basically is, does the code know which html file to append the div to and which html file to use when i use getelementbyid? If not, how do I specify this if I have multiple html files connected to one js file?

Comment: You'll probably have to specify different ids for each of the HTML divs so it can decide.

Comment: If you change the question to "Using the same .js in several HTML files" then it will be better understandable (to you)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you specify the ids of the divs you want to change, it should work.

The js could be like this:

```
var div1 = document.createElement("div")
document.getElementById("id1").appendChild(div1); //matches to div1 in the html

var div2 = document.createElement("div");
document.getElementById("id2").appendChild(div2).  //matches to div2 in the html

var div3 = document.createElement("div")
document.getElementById("id3").appendChild(div3).  //matches to div3 in the html
```

The html could be like this:

```
<div id="id1"></div>

<div id="id2"></div>

<div id="id3"></div>
```